# Как правильно получить jwt токен?

Tags: c#, jwt

Использую либу jose-jwt. При отправке на сервер ругается - говорит malformed jwt. Подскажите где я допустим ошибку

```
string PrivKey = "{" +
    "\"kty\":\"EC\",\"alg\":\"ES256\",\"crv\":\"P-256\"," +
    "\"x\":\"pSH0jvbtVZiseTpJZk0_yfudEIv86uwjeH_gr1qmOGA\"," +
    "\"y\":\"eGdC9EIGmhCheM_T8vhS4Qwk7RfaPRBxF3W5omgBc_M\"," +
    "\"d\":\"DuSjR5eZBp5S-9HNKA8kRQFA_3Akkept-dTbwFoq_3w\"" +
    "}";

var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var jwk = js.Deserialize<IDictionary<string, string>>(PrivKey);


byte[] x = Base64Url.Decode(jwk["x"]);
byte[] y = Base64Url.Decode(jwk["y"]);
byte[] d = Base64Url.Decode(jwk["d"]);


var headers = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
     { "kid", 2}
};

var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "email", "bitzlato.demo@gmail.com" },
        { "aud", "usr" },
        { "iat", ts},
        { "jti", Guid.NewGuid().ToString() },
    };

var privateKey = EccKey.New(x, y, d);

string token = Jose.JWT.Encode(payload, privateKey, JwsAlgorithm.ES256,headers);
```

Comment: Хм, а почему вы ответственный за генерацию JWT? На сколько я понял, вы клиент, а значит это не ваша обязанность, ибо его вам должен дать сервер.

Comment: Сервер даёт мне приват кей. Из него я генерю jwk. Точнее хочу jwk

Comment: Ну тогда этому серверу стоит подумать про безопасность своих ресурсов...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ точнее из приват кей мне нужен токен)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а по моему коду что скажете?

Comment: Ваша задача вообще не должна была существовать, ибо "сервер дает мне приват кей" - приват, на то и приват, что этот ключ должен быть максимально защищен от попадания в сторонние руки, это как дать пароль от банковской ячейки, сразу минус безопасность. JWT - это токен доступа, который сервер подписывает у себя и отдает вам, это его обязанность создать вам токен доступа и только он это может сделать (ибо у него верные ключи шифрования). По этому, данная задача не имеет смысла и сказать тут особо то и нечего, увы.

Comment: По поводу библиотеки - она вам дает верный токен (можете проверить на официальном сайте JWT, который отобразит успешно все данные, если подставите ключ расшифровки). Но, понимаете в чем дело, токен вы и создали, но вот валиден-ли он именно для того сервера, который его требует, м? Сомневаюсь...  И тут получается, что дать адекватный ответ на поставленный вопрос нельзя, ибо это уже индивидуальная задача, которая требует разбора сервера (как он работает и что требует), а этих данных у нас нет. Но тут предположу, что вы просто не так поняли задачу, но увы, без данных мы ее не разберем за вас...